# Facial Emotion recognition with keras, MLP, Landmarks and FER2013

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I'm a bit new to Deep Learning, yet i am trying out a project for facial emotion recognition using FER2013 dataset and keras. The algorythm is quite simple:

1 - Read each image in FER2013 image set (around 30k images 48x48 pixels tagged with an emotion), and extract their 68 landmarks using dlib.
2 - for each image, calculate the mass center of the landmark-defined plan, with coordinates (xmean,ymean).
3 - For each landmark in an image, calculate the euclidian distance between that landmark's coordinates and the mass center (a way to normalize the data);
4 - create a dataset in which each row is a vector containing 68 euclidian distances for each image.

The idea is to create a learning model that doesn't require too much entry info to process, and in this case i end up with a simple 68-dimension vector instead of a (x,y) matrix as input and a 7-dimension vector for output, where each position represents a different emotion (p.ex [1,0,0,0,0,0,0] means neutral, [0,1,0,0,0,0,0] means happy, etc). With this input, i believed that an MLP would suffice and using CNN wouldn't make sense. So i plotted my neural network like this:

```
model = Sequential()

model.add(Dense(68, activation='relu',use_bias=True, 
bias_initializer=RandomUniform(minval=0.01, maxval=0.02), input_dim=68))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(340, use_bias=True, bias_initializer=RandomUniform(minval=0.01, maxval=0.02), activation='relu' ))
model.add(BatchNormalization())

model.add(Dense(7, activation='softmax'))
sgd = SGD(lr=0.00001, decay=0.0, momentum=0.9, nesterov=True)
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=sgd, metrics ['categorical_accuracy'])

score = model.evaluate(training_input,tr_softmaxOut, verbose=0)

history=model.fit(training_input, tr_softmaxOut, validation_split=0.2, epochs=2500, batch_size=10)
score = model.evaluate(test_input, ts_softmaxOut, batch_size=13)
```

I already made several attempts, changing learning rates, decay, varying batch size, changing dropout, and obviously increasing depth and width of the network. Some of them provided obvious overfitting while others actually gave underfitting and no convergence at all, but none of them actually gave an accuracy bigger than 49%.

Can someone please tell me what i'm doing wrong here? And in your experience, is there anything that can be done to increase the accuracy of my MLP? 
Also, do you think CNN would work better in my case? 
Sorry for the newbie questions, it's still an area i'm trying to learn properly.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Please format your code block appropriately - see [How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)

Comment: Done. Thanks for the tip, and sorry, it's also my first post here.